# Will switching to GSM only network switch off data access?

Tags: samsung, mobile-data

I'm using Samsung Note 3 N900 model and i want to make sure i don't connect to internet but continue to make calls & SMS/MMS. Believe this is opposite the query of others.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 (no data at all)

Go to

> Settings --> More Settings --> Mobile Networks --> uncheck "mobile data"

The device will no longer connect to the internet, but continue to receive calls & text. MMS are not possible.

---

## Option 2 (data only for mms)

([source](https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/android-mms-without-data))

Go to

> Settings --> More Settings --> Mobile Networks --> Access Point Names --> Select your data APN --> APN Type

Remove in the field APN type everything but "mms". You have to leave "Mobile Data" **enabled** (see Option 1)

Comment: You can't send MMS with mobile data off. Hence have mentioned an the app in my answer.

Comment: @Pam: Thank you for clarifying this, I edited my answer accordingly to achieve the goal using android tools only.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall) app